# What is the proper way to assign static asset paths in a pinia store to use in component templates

Tags: vuejs3, pinia

I have a website I am making that may be used for other companies of mine and realistically I want to keep certain branding stuff in a single Pinia Store so I can use these variables later globally. My pinia store is as follows:

```
//using composition api in Pinia
import {ref} from 'vue'
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const useCompanyInfoStore = defineStore('companyInfo', () => {
  const facebookLink = ref('https://www.facebook.com/blah/')
  const googleLink = ref('https://www.google.com/maps/place/blah')
  const instagramLink = ref('https://www.instagram.com/blah/')
  const companyLogoLink = ref('~assets/imgs/company-logo.png')

  return {facebookLink, googleLink, instagramLink, companyLogoLink}
})
```

When trying to use the companyLogoLink it cannot find the image path however if I used that string directly in my template it would work and find the image. So I am wondering what would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [import your assets](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#importing-asset-as-url) to get its public URL

```js
import companyLogoLink from '@/assets/imgs/company-logo.png'

export const useCompanyInfoStore = defineStore('companyInfo', () => {
  return {companyLogoLink}
})
```

Then you can use the link anywhere like so:

```js
const store = useCompanyInfoStore()
console.log('this is your link', store.companyLogoLink)
```

Note that, to use `~` or `@` in the file path, you need to config [vite alias](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#resolve-alias) like so:

```js
// vite.config.js
export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
    },
  }
})
```

Comment: Just curious how would this look using it in a template? Like do I need to then do companyInfoStore.companyLogoLink or do I need to use storeToRefs despite this isnt reactive?

Comment: @IrishRedneck You can test it and learn. Anyway, you can use it directly in the template. `storeToRefs` is only for the purpose of extracting properties from the store while keeping its reactivity

Comment: Hey I will accept this answer but could you show how its used in the template? I am so use to using reactive data using not reactive/storetoref I am clueless.

Comment: I also get this error using your implementation above: 1:31:33 PM [vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "~assets/imgs/company-logo.png" from "src/stores/company-info-store.js". Does the file exist?

Comment: I guess you cant use the ~assets but instead need to do ../ for the relative path. I accepted your answer as I figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: @IrishRedneck Please don't accept the answer unless you see it work. Btw, I updated my answer to explain more details

Comment: I do not seem to have a vite.config.js. Should this configuration instead go in quasar.config.js? When setting up this project I did select quasar with vite.

Comment: @IrishRedneck Since I don't use quasar, I'm afraid that I can't help you more. You can try creating `vite.config.js` or search for the corresponding config in quasar

Comment: Looks like quasar keeps their alias in there. EIther way I am selecting your answer as it is basically an equivalent and does work. Thanks